# Super & Sub Class in Java

Tags: java

why we call super class constructor in sub class if we have parameterized constructor of the super class what is the reason that we must call the super class constructor other ways it will get error while extending the sub class?

The first Image is the correct form without error.

[image: Image 1]

The Second image is not the correct form it has error.

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Don't use images to convey textual information. Write the details in the question itself.

Comment: I think a book about java for beginners would help you

Comment: If you dont explicitly call super(...) then no-args super() will be called automatically as the first statement in your subclass's constructor. However, since you did not specify a no-args constructor for the super class, no such constructor can be called. Also note that a no-args constructor will only automatically be created in your super class if no other constructors were defined.

Answer (score 0):

An object that is an instance of a subclass consists of a superclass part (all the member variables and methods of the superclass), with "on top" of that the subclass part (the member variables and methods of the subclass).

When you create an instance of the subclass, the superclass part of the object is initialized first. If the superclass has a constructor that requires arguments, then the subclass constructor has to pass these arguments to the superclass constructor. You do that by calling `super(...)` with the appropriate arguments in the subclass constructor.

See this tutorial: [Oracle Java Tutorials - Using the Keyword `super`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html).